# max length of result when using r studio with markdown?

Tags: markdown, google-visualization, rstudio

I am trying to use googleVis to display my result with R studio and markdown.
I had no problem producing the default Fruits data into motionchart using markdown but when I try to use my own data, markdown refuses to attach it correctly.

After

```
print(M, "chart")
```

is run, I get

```
## <!-- MotionChart generated in R 2.15.0 by googleVis 0.2.16 package -->
## <!-- Thu Jun 07 09:20:56 2012 -->
## 
## 
## <!-- jsHeader -->
## <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
## </script>
## <script type="text/javascript">

.. and so on until

## <!-- divChart -->
##   
## <div id="MotionChartIDa7c4ac2425a"
##   style="width: 600px; height: 500px;">
## </div>
```

I simply don't get why this would not be attached automatically but instead is displaying just the R output. What am I missing out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably starting your codeblock with

````
```{r}
````

You need to start it instead with

````
```{r results='asis'}
````

That will tell it that the output of the codeblock is pure HTML that should be appended directly into the document.